# Calculate $\int \sqrt{4 - \frac{4}{\cos t} + \frac1{\cos^4 t}}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$I = \int \sqrt{4 - \frac{4}{\cos t} + \frac1{\cos^4 t}}dt$$

Not sure what to do.

I tried the change of variable $u = \cos t$,

$$I = \int \frac{\sqrt{4u^4 - 4u^3 + 1}}{u^2} du$$

No idea how to go further.

Comment: Are you sure that you copied everything correctly? According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E(pi%2F2)+sqrt(4-4%2Fcos(x)%2B1%2F(cos(x)%5E4))) this integral does not converge...

Comment: @mrtaurho Near $0$ the integrand behaves like $1/u^2,$ so indeed, it doesn't converge.

Comment: I'll edit to have it an indefinite integral

Comment: Maybe it's better to edit the question with how you arrived at that definite integral because there can be a mistake on the road. Many definite integrals can be solved whereas solving an indefinite one is pretty nasty sometimes.

Comment: Is the middle term in the radical in the original integrand perhaps supposed to be $-\frac{4}{\cos^{\color{red}{2}} t}$? That makes the integral elementary, but I doubt there's a closed-form antiderivative in terms of elementary functions for the integrand in $t$.